# raw socket lump my packages, but I want it be real-time

Tags: linux, sockets, real-time

I'm trying to make an EtherCAT master on my Beaglebone Black board, I replace the kernel image to v4.18 with Xenomai 3.3.

I have a little demo to describe the basic mechanism. To simplify my problem, I delete some useless codes.

```
int socketfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
sigemptyset(&sigset);
sigaddset(&sigset, SIGALRM);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);
timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, &timer);
timer_settime(timer, 0, &interval, NULL);
while(1)
{
    sigwaitinfo(&sigset, &siginfo);
    sendto(socketfd, data, len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
}
```

While the code start running, packages are captured by another PC via Wireshark.

And on Wireshark's monitor:
[Wireshark Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FCOS.png)

As I set the interval time to 500us, you can see some packages can arrive in time, but some are lumped to be send at a same time.

If I change the interval to 100us, may be tree or four packages are lumped.

Packages will stop lumping only if I set the interval to above 1ms.

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem? Or I can only run this code at a period above 1ms?

Comment: Have you instrumented your code to make sure that it's reliably running at the right time? It's important to know whether the issue is with packet transmission or you loop's timing.